# How to find the actual object class from any array in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular

When an array of `SomeClass` is assigned to an array of any, e.g.

```
export class MyClass {
    private anyArray: any[];
    public setArray(a: any[]) {
        this.anyArray = a;
    }
}
```

where in this case `a` is an array of `SomeClass` objects.

Is there any way I can find the actual class type of the array objects (i.e. `SomeClass`) from `anyArray` later on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `a.constructor.name` to get the name of the class.

Comment: Isn't that just the name of the class of a (i.e. Array)? I want the class of the objects in the array.

Comment: No, it's not. In this case it would be `a.name`.